# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Web3Provider')

Tags: node.js, blockchain, metamask, ethers.js

please i am trying to use ethers to connect my app to metamask but i kept getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
[image]

this is my code to connect to metamask

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";

export const connectWallet = async() => {
  try {
     if(window.ethereum != undefined) {
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
      // MetaMask requires requesting permission to connect users accounts
      await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
      const signer = provider.getSigner()
     } else {
        alert("you need to install metamask https://metamask.io/")
     }
  }catch(err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

then i imported connectWallet into my react component
[image]

this is my button
[image]
(reading 'Web3Provider') on my browser console.